# Programmatically selecting a segment in UISegmentedControl based on title of that segment

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` with several segments, each with a different "title".  I want to be able to read in a `NSString`, and programmatically select the segment whose title matches that string.  Say I start with something like:

```
NSString *stringToMatch = @"foo";
UISegmentedControl *seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz", nil]];
```

---

I want to do something like:

```
[seg selectSegmentWithTitle:stringToMatch];
```

But since there is no method called `selectSegmentWithTitle`, this doesn't work.  Is anyone aware of a method that would be similar to this though?

---

I've also thought of looping over all the titles in `seg`, similar to this:

```
int i = 0;
for (UISegment *thisSeg in [seg allSegmentsInOrder])
{
    if ([thisSeg.title isEqualToString:stringToMatch])
    {
        [seg setSelectedSegmentIndex:i];
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

but to my knowledge there is no such thing as `UISegment`, nor is there a method `allSegmentsInOrder`.  Again, does anyone know of any changes I could make to get this to work?

---

Thirdly, I could probably subclass UISegmentedControl to somehow add the methods I want it to have.  I hate subclassing like that though, cause I'd have to go and re-declare all my segments and other inconvenient things like that.  But it may be the only way to go...

---

Perhaps the way to do this is totally different from the three ideas I listed above.  I'm open to whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So while I was typing this question up, I kept searching and realized that my second method from OP is pretty close.  I figured I should still post what I came up with, in case someone else is looks for something like this in the future.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [seg numberOfSegments]; i++)
{
    if ([[seg titleForSegmentAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:stringToMatch])
    {
        [seg setSelectedSegmentIndex:i];
        break;
    }
    //else {Do Nothing - these are not the droi, err, segment we are looking for}
}
if ([seg selectedSegmentIndex] == -1)
{
    NSLog(@"Error - segment with title %@ not found in seg",stringToMatch);
    NSLog(@"Go back and fix your code, you forgot something");
    // prob should do other stuff here to let the user know something went wrong
}
```

This still feels a little hacky, and is probably against some best practice guide somewhere, but if there's a finite list of titles and you can be certain `stringToMatch` will always be on that list, I'm thinking it should be fine.